# Do processes always consume battery and cpu or are they neutral on cpu and memory usage while "inactive"?

Tags: windows, process, power-management, cpu-usage

If a process in Windows OS is currently inactive (not doing any work) does that mean that it doesn't consume any power and cpu/gpu resources?

Answer (score 0):

If a process is **suspended**, it does not consume CPU or GPU resouces, though it may have RAM reserved. A suspended process should have little impact on power usage, with the *caveat* that there might conceivably be a small use for RAM, if it forces other processes to swap memory.

[image: Suspended Process]

Comment: As far as I am concerned, keeping information in RAM requires energy